# What has been the accepted value for the Avogadro constant in the "CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics" over the years?

Tags: physical-chemistry

Some questions about the constant made me curious as to exactly how much the accepted value has changed over the years. I am pretty sure that I learned a rounded value of $6.023\times10^{23}$ about 1970 which would have been around the 50th edition. I know that sometime after that the accepted value rounded to 4 significant figures was $6.022\times10^{23}$. Of course since 2019 the accepted value has been fixed at exactly $6.02214076\times10^{23}$

It would seem that the CRC handbook is a reasonable source for the accepted value of the constant since it has been updated almost yearly.

**Please update the table in the answer in the community wiki page with other values**

Comment: You can find the value in [past CODATA publications](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Constants/index.html). This is probably the most reliable and easily found historical record.

Comment: See [Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xYNS.png) in Becker, P. History and Progress in the Accurate Determination of the Avogadro Constant. *Rep. Prog. Phys.* 2001, 64 (12), 1945–2008. DOI: [10.1088/0034-4885/64/12/206](https://doi.org/10.1088/0034-4885/64/12/206). It covers year up to the year 2001 and is going to save a lot of time.

Answer (score 17):

I dislike offsite image links since they disappear over time. So below is Table 1 from andselisk's comment on the question.

The paper itself is behind a firewall and I can't see it.

> See **Table 1** in Becker, P. History and Progress in the Accurate Determination of the Avogadro Constant. Rep. Prog. Phys. 2001, 64 (12), 1945–2008. DOI: [10.1088/0034-4885/64/12/206](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0034-4885/64/12/206). It covers year up to the year 2001 and is going to save a lot of time. – andselisk
>
> [image]

Comment: Couple of things about the table. (1) It shows individual values determined by experimenters with improving exactness. The CRC data and CODATA show weighted values. (2) the basis for the AMU changed in 1961 from oxygen-16 to carbon-12. I don't think that the table corrects for that. (3) I'm assuming that $\mathrm{u_{rel}}$ is an absolute value not a % value. // The particular article is behind a firewall that I can see.

Answer (score 12):

**Please edit the table to include missing data**

Avogadro constant in the "CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics"

| Edition | Years(s) | page | value | CODATA? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 [(Link)](https://books.google.com/books?id=07AHIEp6vYQC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) | 1913 | -- | Not Given | -- |
| 2 | 1914 |  |  | No |
| 3 [(Link)](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.32044019690874&view=1up&seq=127) | 1914 | 123 | 6.42(31) × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 4 | 1915 |  | 6.42(31) × 10<sup>23</sup> (note) | No |
| 5 | 1917 |  | 6.42(31) × 10<sup>23</sup> (note) | No |
| 6 [(Link)](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uiug.30112063064916&view=1up&seq=291&q1=%22number%20of%20molecules%22) | 1917 | 286 | 6.42(31) × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 7 [(Link)](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.31822008341844&view=1up&seq=373&q1=%22number%20of%20molecules%22) | 1918 | 369 | 6.42(31) × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 8 [(Link)](https://tinyurl.com/y756ahcb) | 1920 | 523 | 6.06 × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 9 [(Link)](https://tinyurl.com/y8xzm6we) | 1922 | 605 | 6.06 × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 10 [(Link)](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.$b620080&view=1up&seq=694&q1=%22number%20of%20molecules%22) | 1924 | 678 | 6.06 × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 11 [(Link)](https://openlibrary.org/works/OL15141507W/Handbook_of_chemistry_and_physics?edition=handbookofchemis00chem) | 1926 | 784 | 6.06 × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 12 | 1927 | 884 | 6.06 × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 13 | 1928 | 986 | 6.06 × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 14 | 1929 | 1151 | 6.06 × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 15 | 1930 |  |  | No |
| 16 | 1931 | 1244 | 6.064(6) × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 17 | 1932 |  | 6.064(6) × 10<sup>23</sup> (Note) | No |
| 18 | 1933 | 1488 | 6.064(6) × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 19 | 1934 | 1890 | 6.064(6) × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 20 | 1935 |  | 6.064(6) × 10<sup>23</sup> (Note) | No |
| 21 | 1936 | 1980 | 6.064(6) × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 22 | 1937 | 2026 | 6.064(6) × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 23 | 1939 | 2177 | 6.064(6) × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 24 | 1940 | 2519 | 6.064(6) × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 25 | 1941 | 2454 | 6.064(6) × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 26 | 1942 | 2403 | 6.0228(11) × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 27 | 1943 | 2499 | 6.0228(11) × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 28 | 1944 | 2517 | 6.0228(11) × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 29 | 1945 | 2585 | 6.0228(11) × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 30 [(Link)](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.169228) | 1946 | 2631 | 6.0228(11) × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 30(Rev) | 1947 | 2631 | 6.0228(11) × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 31 [(Link)](https://archive.org/details/handbookofchemis01chem/page/n3/mode/2up) | 1949 | 2683 | 6.0228(11) × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 32 | 1950 | 2811 | 6.0228(11) × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 33 | 1951 | 2833 | 6.0228(11) × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 34 | 1952 |  |  | No |
| 35 | 1953 | 3092 | 6.0228(11) × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 36 | 1954 | 3104 | 6.025 44(11) × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 37 | 1955 | 3080 | 6.0228(11) × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 38 | 1956 | 3136 | 6.0247(2) × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 39 [(Link)](https://archive.org/details/handbookofchemi00hodg/page/n5/mode/2up) | 1957 | 3134 | 6.0228(11) × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 40 | 1958 | 3376 | 6.022 8(11) × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 41 | 1959 | 3301 | 6.022 8(11) × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 42 | 1960 | 3399 | 6.022 8(11) × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 43 | 1961 |  |  | No |
| 44 | 1962 |  |  | No |
| 45 | 1964 | F-95 | 6.022 57(9) × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 46 | 1965 |  |  | No |
| 47 | 1966-1967 | F-138 | 6.022 52(28) × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 48 | 1967-1968 |  |  | No |
| 49 | 1968–1969 | F-167 | 6.022 52(28) × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 50 | 1969-1970 | F-168 | 6.022 52(28) × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 51 | 1970-1971 |  |  |  |
| 52 [(Link)](https://archive.org/details/crchandbookofche00crcp) | 1971-1972 | F-189 | 6.022 169(40) × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 53 | 1972-1973 | F195 | 6.022 169(40) × 10<sup>23</sup> |  |
| 54 | 1973-1974 |  |  |  |
| 55 [(Link)](https://archive.org/details/crchandbookofche00weas) | 1974-1975 | F-222 | 6.022 169(40) × 10<sup>23</sup> | No |
| 56 | 1975–1976 |  | 6.022 045(31) × 10<sup>23</sup> |  |
| 57 [(Link)](https://archive.org/details/crchandbookofche00clev) | 1976–1977 | F-242 | 6.022 045(31) × 10<sup>23</sup> | Yes, bulletin #11 |
| 58 | 1977-1978 | F-242 | 6.022 045(31) × 10<sup>23</sup> | Yes, bulletin #11 |
| 59 | 1978-1979 | F-250 | 6.022 045(31) × 10<sup>23</sup> | Yes, bulletin #11 |
| 60 | 1979-1980 | F-244 | 6.022 045(31) × 10<sup>23</sup> | Yes, bulletin #11 |
| 61 | 1980-1981 |  |  |  |
| 62 | 1981-1982 |  |  |  |
| 63 | 1982-1983 |  |  |  |
| 64 [(Link)](https://archive.org/details/crchandbookofche0000unse) | 1983-1984 | F-198 | 6.022 045(31) × 10<sup>23</sup> | Yes |
| 65 [(Link)](https://archive.org/details/crchandbookofche0000unse1984-1985) | 1984-1985 | F-192 | 6.022 045(31) × 10<sup>23</sup> | Yes |
| 66 | 1985-1986 |  |  |  |
| 67 | 1986-1987 |  |  |  |
| 68 | 1987-1988 |  |  |  |
| 69 | 1988-1989 |  |  |  |
| 70 | 1989-1990 | F-215 & F-217 | 6.022 1367(36) × 10<sup>23</sup> | Yes, 1986 |
| 71 [(Link)](https://archive.org/details/handbookofchemis00crcp) | 1990-1991 | 1-1 | 6.022 1367(36) × 10<sup>23</sup> | Yes, 1986 |
| 72 [(Link)](https://archive.org/details/crchandbookofche0lide) | 1991-1992 | 1-1 | 6.022 1367(36) × 10<sup>23</sup> | Yes, 1986 |
| 73 | 1992-1993 |  |  |  |
| 74 | 1993-1994 |  |  |  |
| 75 | 1994-1995 |  |  |  |
| 76 | 1995-1996 |  |  |  |
| 77 | 1996-1997 |  |  |  |
| 78 | 1997-1998 |  |  |  |
| 79 | 1998-1999 |  |  |  |
| 80 | 1999-2000 |  |  |  |
| 81 [Link](https://archive.org/details/crchandbookofche81lide) | 2000-2001 | 1-7 | 6.022 141 99(47) × 10<sup>23</sup> | Yes, 1998 |
| 82 | 2001–2002 | 1-7 | 6.022 141 99(47) × 10<sup>23</sup> | Yes, 1998 |
| 83 | 2002-2003 |  | 6.022 141 99(47) × 10<sup>23</sup> (Note) | (Yes, 1998) |
| 84 | 2003–2004 | 1-7 | 6.022 141 99(47) × 10<sup>23</sup> | Yes, 1998 |
| 85 | 2004-2005 | 1-2 | 6.022 141 5(10) × 10<sup>23</sup> | Yes, 2002 |
| 86 | 2005–2006 | 1-5 | 6.022 141 5(10) × 10<sup>23</sup> | Yes, 2002 |
| 87 | 2006–2007 | 1-5 | 6.022 141 5(10) × 10<sup>23</sup> | Yes, 2002 |
| 88 | 2007–2008 | 1-1 | 6.022 141 5(10) × 10<sup>23</sup> | Yes, 2002 |
| 89 [(Link)](https://archive.org/details/crchandbookofche00davi) | 2008-2009 | 1-1 | 6.022 141 79(30) × 10<sup>23</sup> | Yes, 2006 |
| 90 | 2009-2010 | 1-1 | 6.022 141 79(30) × 10<sup>23</sup> | Yes, 2006 |
| 91 | 2010-2011 |  | 6.022 141 79(30) × 10<sup>23</sup> (Note) | (Yes, 2006) |
| 92 | 2011–2012 | 1-1 | 6.022 141 79(30) × 10<sup>23</sup> | Yes, 2006 |
| 93 | 2012–2013 | 1-2 | 6.022 141 29(27) × 10<sup>23</sup> | Yes, 2010 |
| 94 | 2013–2014 | 1-2 | 6.022 141 29(27) × 10<sup>23</sup> | Yes, 2010 |
| 95 | 2014–2015 | 1-2 | 6.022 141 29(27) × 10<sup>23</sup> | Yes, 2010 |
| 96 | 2015–2016 | 1-2 | 6.022 141 29(27) × 10<sup>23</sup> | Yes, 2010 |
| 97 [(Link)](https://archive.org/details/crchandbookofchemistryandphysicsareadyreferencebookofchemicalandphysicaldatacrcpress2016) | 2016–2017 | 1-1 | 6.022 140 857(74) × 10<sup>23</sup> | Yes, 2014 |
| 98 | 2017-2018 |  | 6.022 140 857(74) × 10<sup>23</sup> (Note) | (Yes, 2014) |
| 99 | 2019-2020 |  | 6.022 140 857(74) × 10<sup>23</sup> (Note) | (Yes, 2014) |
| 100 | 2020-2021 |  | 6.022 140 857(74) × 10<sup>23</sup> (Note) | (Yes, 2014) |
| >101? | 2021-2022 | ? | 6.022 140 76 × 10<sup>23</sup> (exact) | Yes, 2018 |

**NOTES FOR TABLE**

- Early editions are actually titled "Handbook of Chemistry and Physics". Not sure when the title formally switched to the "CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics".
- Some early editions are available [online at HathiTrust](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/000550929). The "Limited search" editions can only be searched for a hit. There is no page number or preview for the found text.
- The first edition that I found to hit on the phrase "Avogadro number" was the 16th edition. It would seem to that phrase until at least the 31st edition.
- By 84th edition the phrase was changed to "Avogadro constant"
- A CODATA newsletter had a list of publications which listed: *No. 11 (Dec 1973) 8 pp, Recommended Consistent Values of the Fundamental Physical Constants, 1973 (Report of the CODATA Task Group on Fundamental Constants, August 1973).*

**1st Edition**

The link is to the facsimile edition.

**3rd edition (c)1914**

This version is online at HathiTrust. An [old edit](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=CRC_Handbook_of_Chemistry_and_Physics&oldid=567082333) of the Wikipedia article  [CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRC_Handbook_of_Chemistry_and_Physics) indicates the third edition has 322 pages.

**3rd thru 12th Editions**

In at least the 3rd through 12th editions of the CRC Handbook in have a "Heat" category in the Table of Contents where there is an entry for "Number of molecules in a molecule-gram" which points to a table with three values. Note also that none of these three values are in Becker's paper. (Only seen 1st, 3rd, and 6th through 12th editions)

> [image]
>
> My calculation is that the mean = $6.42(31)\times 10^{23}$
>
> Millikan 1910 would seem to be from rounding $6.18^\times10^{23}$ value in  [Phil.Mag. Feb,1910,209](https://archive.org/details/londonedinburg6191910lond/page/228/mode/1up)

**4th and 5th edition**
See likely that these editions are same as 3rd and 6th.

**8th through ? edition**

In at least the 8th through 12th editions of the CRC Handbook the Table of Contents contains a category "Miscellaneous Tables" which has a link to "Atomic and Molecular Constants" which references the "Smithsonian Tables" and gives a value of $6.06\times10^{23}$ for the "Number of molecules in a gram molecule".

The reference to the *Smithsonian Physical Tables*doesn't give any more indication as to which tables those are. This seems to be the [2nd reprint of 6th rev. ed. Prepared by Frederick E. Fowle. in 1916](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=coo1.ark:/13960/t5h99p81p&view=1up&seq=384&q1=%226.06%22)

**13th through and 30th(?) Editions**

There is another version of the table *Number of Molecules in a Gram-Molecule* which has four values.

- In the 13th, 14th, 16th, 18th, 19th, 23rd, 25th, 26th and 27th editions the table is listed in the table of contents in the *Heat* section.
- In the 29th, 30th and 30th (rev) editions the table is listed in the table of contents in the *Miscellaneous* section.
- The table is gone in the 31st edition (and presumably in any subsequent editions).

> [image]

**16th, 18th, 19th, 21st, 23rd, 24th, 25th and 27th Editions**

These editions have identical entries, listing it as "Avogadro's number" in a table named "Probable Values of the General Physical Constants" which is in the "Miscellaneous Tables" section of the Table of Contents. The tables cite [Raymond T. Birge: The Physical Review Supplement, Vol. 1, No. 1, July, 1929](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.1.1), as the source for the entire "Probable Values of the General Physical Constants" table. Note however that the value given here doesn't match the one attributed to R T Birge in 1929 in [Becker, P. "History and Progress in the Accurate Determination of the Avogadro Constants"](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/144402/what-has-been-the-accepted-value-for-the-avogadro-constant-in-the-crc-handbook/144406#144406)

**17th, 19th, 20th, and 22nd Editions**

These editions are book ended by editions which have the same value. These editions are assumed to have this value too.

**28th, 29th, 30th, 30th (rev), 31st, 32nd and 35th Editions**

*The 30th revised edition has "Revised" above "Thirtieth Edition" on the title page*

Listed as "Avogadro number (chemical scale)" in "New Table of Values of the General Physical Constants." The table is listed in the "Miscellaneous" section of the Table of Contents.

Cites: *Raymond T. Birge: The Physical Review Supplement, Vol. 13, 233, 1941* as the source for the entire table. (This is the value listed for R T Birge in 1941 in *Becker, P. "History and Progress in the Accurate Determination of the Avogadro Constants"*. With the quoted error the extra 3 is unnecessary.)

> The reference is better known as: "A New Table of Values of the General Physical Constants (as of August, 1941)", Raymond T. Birge
> Rev. Mod. Phys. 13, 233 (1941) [DOI: 10.1103/RevModPhys.13.233](https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.13.233)

**36th edition**

Value found in table of "Atomic Constants" which references James W. M. DuMond and E. Richard Cohen, Physical Review 82:555, 1951

**38th edition**

Found in table of "Atomic Constants" which references "A survey of Atomic Constants (1955) by J. A. Bearden and John H. Thomsen, The John Hopkins University"

**40th, 41st and 42nd Editions**

This cites Raymond T. Birge: Reviews of Modern Physics 13, 233, 1941. This matches the value attributed to Birge in the same year by Becker. (Because of the error the extra 3 is superfluous so I left it off.)

**45th Edition**

"Avogadro's Number" in table "Values of the General Physical Constants" which simply states "Furnished by R. D. Huntoon."

**50th Edition**

Cites source for data in Table named "Physical Constants" as "National Bureau of Standards Technical News Bulletin, October 1963."

**52th, 53rd and 55th editions**

References [Rev. Mod. Phys 41, 375 (1969)](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.41.375)

**56th edition**

From user  theorist's comment on this post.

**57th, 58th, 59th, and 60th Editions**

*Avogadro Constant* in table *Recommended Consistent Values of the Fundamental Physical Constants.*

Table cites: *Data from CODATA Bulletin No. 11, ICSU CODATA Central Office, CODATA Secretariat: 19 Westendstrasse, 6 Frankfurt/Main, German Federal Republic (copies of this bulletin are available at no cost from this office).*

**64th and 65th editions**

*Avogadro Constant* in table titled *Recommended Consistent Values of the Fundamental Physical Constants*.

Table cites: *Data from CODATA Bulletin No. 11, ICSU CODATA Central Office, CODATA Secretariat: 51 Boulevard de Montmorency, 75016 Paris, France (copies of this bulletin are available at no cost from this office).*

**70th through 72nd Editions**

Cites 1986 CODATA values as published in E. Richard Cohen and Barry N. Taylor, Journal of Research of the National Bureau of Standards, 92, 85, 1987.

**83rd edition**

Based on pattern of CODATA being used for 4 years.

**84th edition**

calculated page number from [on-line pdf file](http://fap.if.usp.br/%7Ejhsevero/Fisica_Experimental_C_Semestral_2020/crc.pdf)

**85th edition**

[Internet edition](https://www.academia.edu/28803942/CRC_Handbook_of_Chemistry_and_Physics_Editor_in_Chief)

**85th edition**

Got value via "Look Inside" at Amazon

**90th edition**

Based on the 2006 CODATA recommended values

**91st edition**

Surely same as 90th and 92nd data. Pattern of using CODATA for four Years.

**92nd edition**

From print copy (MaxW)

**98th through 100th Editions**

Based on pattern of CODATA being used for four years.

Comment: The 56th edition (1975-1976) has it as 6.022045(31) x 10^23. Since the uncertainty gives the estimated value an upper bound of 6.022076 x 10^23, it seems they underestimated the uncertainty. The uncertainty they'd need to encompass the value at the redefiniton is 6.022045(97) x 10^23.

Comment: I chose the CRC handbook because it has been published for about as long as scientists have been able to determine a reasonably accurate value, and it is updated yearly. Given the CODATA values it seems worth noting CRC's reliance on that data, so added a column to track that.

Comment: @theorist - Typically the error number is the standard deviation. So  (6.022140 - 6.022045)/0.000031 =  3.06 standard deviations which doesn't seem horrible.

Comment: 3.06 stand deviations means that, according to their predicted uncertainty, there was only a 1:500 chance that the actual value would be that far from their predicted value.  If you subsequently asked those who provided that value about this, I think they themselves would acknowledge they significantly underestimated the uncertainty.

Answer (score 10):

The [Committee on Data of the International Science Council (CODATA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Committee_on_Data_for_Science_and_Technology) was established as ICSU Committee on Data for Science and Technology in 1966.

Avogadro constant, [CODATA recommended values](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Constants/index.html)

| Year(s) | page | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [1969](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/1969RMP.pdf#page=103) | 477 | 6.022 169(40) × 10<sup>23</sup> |
| [1973](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/1973JPCRD.pdf#page=56) | 718 | 6.022045(31) × 10<sup>23</sup> |
| [1986](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/codata86.pdf#page=6) | 6 | 6.022 136 7(36) × 10<sup>23</sup> |
| [1998](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/all_1998.pdf#page=6) | 6 | 6.022 141 99(47) × 10<sup>23</sup> |
| [2002](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/all_2002.pdf#page=6) | 6 | 6.022 141 5(10) × 10<sup>23</sup> |
| [2006](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/all_2006.pdf#page=7) | 7 | 6.022 141 79(30) × 10<sup>23</sup> |
| [2010](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/all_2010.pdf#page=5) | 5 | 6.022 141 29(27) × 10<sup>23</sup> |
| [2014](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/all_2014.pdf#page=5) | 5 | 6.022 140 857(74) × 10<sup>23</sup> |
| [2018](https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Category?view=pdf&All+values.x=72&All+values.y=9#page=5) | 5 | 6.022 140 76 × 10<sup>23</sup> (exact) |

**NOTES FOR TABLE**

**2018** - exact by new definition of constant

Comment: I wonder if it would be helpful to note that the definition of mole was standardized to a new definition in 1971: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant#SI_definition_of_1971

Comment: @Zhe - The values do need to be corrected. In 1961 the amu was based on 1/12 of a $\ce{^{12}C}$ atom, so 1 amu was $1.0\bar0$ g/mol. With the 2018 suggested values now accepted, the molar mass constant is now 0.999 999 999 65(30) g/mol. So if I figured this correctly the values from 1969 to 2014 need to be multiplied by 0.999 999 999 65.

Comment: @Zhe - pragmatically the 0.999 999 999 65 correction only changes the value if there are at least 9 decimal places in the value.

Comment: Oh, yes, practically, there's no difference, but it just felt weird to juxtapose values with (slightly) different meanings.

Answer (score 7):

Here are plots of the historical CODATA and CRC values for $N_{\text {A}}$ listed in MaxW's posts.  Plots were made in Mathematica.

I've provided plots with successively later lower bounds for the dates, and correspondingly smaller $N_{\text {A}}$ ranges, so that the shrinking uncertainties in later years can be visualized.

N.B.: When the CRC value had a two-year range, I averaged the years (e.g., 1975-76 became 1975.5). When the CRC values were repeated in successive editions, I plotted only the earlier value.

The last three of the four CRC values shown each correspond to the CODATA value from 3–5 years past.  This suprised me—especially with its emphasis on yearly updates, I would have thought the CRC would be kept more up-to-date than that.  I wonder if this is generally the case for data in the CRC—that data updates stop a few years before the publication date, to give time for proofreading, typesetting, etc.

1998 CODATA => 2003–04 CRC

2002 CODATA => 2005 CRC

2006 CODATA => 2010 CRC

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]